# Can't verify contract on etherscan Rinkeby

Tags: etherscan, verify

So I deployed a contract, `CErc20Delegator`, on Rinkeby using hardhat-deploy, but I'm struggling to verify the contract on etherscan.

This is the deploy script:

```
  const deployment = await deploy("CUsdcDelegator", {
    from: deployer,
    args: [
      "0x4dbcdf9b62e891a7cec5a2568c3f4faf9e8abe2b", // USDC address on Rinkeby
      comptroller.address, // 0x4dB8F89cb631A473e8840cb4eFF10aEee0C53131
      interestRateModel.address, // 0xD3EA19C495828fA7fA17F549644f5252C92dD66A
      ethers.utils.parseUnits("2", 14).toString(),
      "Compound USDC Token",
      "cUSDC",
      "8",
      deployer, // 0x5D3e4C0FE11e0aE4c32F0FF74B4544C49538AC61
      cUsdcDelegate.address, // 0xee3866B3bE533B4667B831a332078097e9Db04ab
      "0x00",
    ],
    log: true,
    deterministicDeployment: false,
    contract: "CErc20Delegator",
    gasLimit: 4000000,
  });
```

- I flattened the contract using [flatten-sol](https://github.com/ngduc/flatten-sol), which I've uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/cryptofish7/a68614f146b6397e803e15a818331b0a).
- Double checked that the flattened contract compiles in Remix.
- Constructed the ABI-encoded arguments using https://abi.hashex.org/ which returned:

```
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
```

[image]

- Then tried to verify with optimizations enabled and runs set to 200.

Despite this, the contract still fails to verify.

Comment: but why you didn't deploy it from remix?

Comment: I still have to verify it regardless right?

Comment: you can deploy it from there first and see this stuff